# How do I change the latex font when usetex=True for matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to use a local font as the math font for matplotlib when I set `usetex=True`.
According to matplotlib's website ([Text rendering with LaTeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html)), the following is an appropriate way to change the font when `usetex=True`.

```
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "sans-serif",
    "font.sans-serif": "Helvetica",
})
```

However, when I try this the font does not change.

I have done the following. I start with the default font in the top plot, then I try two different methods to change the font. However, all fonts look the same. The result is below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# Removing unecessary and distracting lines/labels
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.spines.bottom'] = False
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.spines.left']   = False
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.spines.right']  = False
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.spines.top']    = False
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.size']    = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']    = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.major.size']    = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.labelsize']    = 0
# print(matplotlib.rcParams.keys())

testString = r'Thrust Coefficient \\ $\displaystyle \mathbf{C_T}$'

matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 36
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True
})

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)
ax1.text(0.5,0.5, testString, ha='center')

# Font Change
# Setting all the math text types to my desired font
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'Neo Euler'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'Neo Euler'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'Neo Euler'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.sf'] = 'Neo Euler'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'Neo Euler'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fallback'] = None
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'sf'
# Also using matplotlib suggested method
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "sans-serif",
    "font.sans-serif": "Neo Euler",
})
ax2.text(0.5,0.5, testString, ha='center')

font = {
    'family': 'Neo Euler',
}
ax3.text(0.5,0.5, testString, ha='center', fontdict=font)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

All the fonts look the same. I am not sure what step I am missing or what went wrong. I get the desired result when `usetex=False`. However, I would like the extra features available with `usetex`, like the linebreaks.
[image: The resulting plot]

Comment: I have noticed if I put in random characters for my fonts names I do not get an error, so it seems that `rcParams` is not updated. For example, using `"font.sans-serif": "sdafdsaaf"` inside the `plt.rcParams.update` function does not produce any warning or error.

Comment: The above is only true is `usetex=True`

Comment: I get the impression that `usetex=True` ignores the font settings and matplotlib and uses font settings in TeX. However, if that is the case why would the website specifically recommend changing font settings after setting `usetex=True`.